# How can i get shopping cart info using order item id (Kentico)

Tags: c#, kentico

I am getting shopping cart info using order id as shown in below

> var shoppingcartInfo
>   =ShoppingCartInfoProvider.GetShoppingCartInfoFromOrder(OrderId)

but i want to get the shopping cart info using the orderitemid , is there any possible way to get the cart item.

Thanks

Comment: More information is needed to answer your question thoroughly for example; how are you getting `orderid` currently? Is it a property on another object? Please see the following post;

How to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe clarify your question a bit more.  Do you want to get the shopping cart info or the shopping cart item info?  The "item" info is a line item, whereas the shopping cart is the shopping cart header.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more detail, but it looks (based on the available [documentation](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_2/api/html/T_CMS_Ecommerce_ShoppingCartInfoProvider.htm) and a quick google search) like the following methods are your best options and none of them explicitly use `orderitemid`.

```
public static ShoppingCartInfo GetShoppingCartInfo(int userId, string siteName)
public static ShoppingCartInfo GetShoppingCartInfoFromOrder(int orderId)
public static ShoppingCartItemInfo GetShoppingCartItem(ShoppingCartInfo cart, int cartItemId)
```

As I stated previously you need [more detail in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) than what you have provided for a more thorough answer. There are many methods available to you, just read through the documentation and pick the one that best meets your needs. With more information, I can edit my answer to better help with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `OrderItemId`, you should be able to do a double hop:

```
var orderItem = OrderItemInfoProvider.GetOrderItemInfo(orderItemId);
var shoppingcartInfo = ShoppingCartInfoProvider.GetShoppingCartInfoFromOrder(orderItem.OrderItemOrderID);
```

I hope that works for you.  If you need the individual cart item, try:

```
var orderItem = OrderItemInfoProvider.GetOrderItemInfo(orderItemId);
var order = OrderInfoProvider.GetOrderInfo(orderItem.OrderItemOrderID); 
var shoppingcartItemInfo = ShoppingCartItemInfoProvider.GetShoppingCartItemInfo(order, orderItem.OrderItemSKU);
```